# SQLite3 / PDO - No such table though it does exist

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I have a problem with an SQLite3 database where I can access it either with the sqlite3 command or with the PHPStorm built-in database manager but the application I am working on doesn't find the tables in it. It correctly connects to the database it seems.

This line of PHP causes the PDOException:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$results = self::$app->db->query($query);
```

And the exception is simply `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: users`. I am using the Slim framework, by the way.

I don't really know what to do as I am new to Slim as well as SQLite.

Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but I'd recommend that you try to tag this with some kind of slim framework tag as as the prerequisities for your code snippet needs to be known (and they're probably a part of the slim framework) - so you probably wanna get some answers from people who actually works with the framework : ) My best shot would be that you didn't setup your configuration files correctly though.

Comment: Thanks, I did. I thought that it was only related to PDO or SQLite but I am not sure, so...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The database that you have opened does not contain this table.

SQLite will happily open any file name; if it does not exist, it will create a new, empty database.

Check your database file name.

Comment: I did not know about the automatic creation of the database, but mine is correct and exists. The app.db file is in the parent folder of the script containing the two lines I pasted. It seems to open it correctly because I have no other app.db file created anywhere.

Comment: The evidence shows that the database path you're using is not correct.

Comment: Well, I just tried with an absolute path to the .db file and it worked. I feel a bit stupid not to have tried this in first...
But I wonder, what should be the reference with a relative path? Relative to the PHP script did not work as I tried it, but it surely was a path problem as an absolute path solved the problem.

Anyway, thank you!

Comment: A relative path is based on the *current* directory, which in PHP, is random.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the accepted answer that pointed me in the right direction.
I am using Symfony 4.1 and realized that the base directory for Symfony is the `public` directory (should be `app` in 2.8) so to open my database I had to do :

```
# file: PROJECT_ROOT/.env
DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///../my_super.db"
```

But then, every call to doctrine in a command (like `doctrine:schema:update`) must be called in a direct subfolder of the project, like so:

`PROJECT_ROOT/bin$ ./console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`